# How to include a Python programmed game in HTML?

Tags: python, html, include

I'm practicing and want to start a new simple web page. I'm a Python and HTML beginner,
and I had a simple idea...
To program a simple "rock, paper, scissors" game to be played in a console (I haven't started that code yet) and upload it to my personal page and let people to be able to play the game against the computer, inside my page. 
Is there any way to do that? just like including javascript code maybe or something. 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some of projects for that like:

- [Skulpt](http://www.skulpt.org/)
- [Brython](http://www.brython.info/)
- [Titanium](http://www.appcelerator.com/platform/titanium-platform/)
- [IronPython](http://ironpython.net/browser/)